# Xamarin forms ios webview customRenderer to basic authentication

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to use basic authentication with Xamarin Forms, for iOS specifically.

I have a custom WebView renderer to achieve this.

I saw this sample in Xamarin.ios; how can i get it working in my custom renderer?

```
public class WebViewDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate, INSUrlConnectionDataDelegate
{

    public override void DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(WKWebView webView, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge, Action<NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSUrlCredential> completionHandler)
    {
        //base.DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(webView, challenge, completionHandler);
        completionHandler(NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, new NSUrlCredential("username", "password", NSUrlCredentialPersistence.ForSession));
        Console.WriteLine("We are authenticated");
        return;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to use `WKWebView` and `WKNavigationDelegate` in the Xamarin.Forms.

Firstly, create a custom WebView with a bindable property in the forms:

```
public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Uri",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(CustomWebView),
        defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then in the custom renderer, we can get this uri and set it to the new WKWebView to show the web page:

```
public class MyCustomWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomWebView, WKWebView>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            var webView = new WKWebView(Frame, new WKWebViewConfiguration());
            webView.NavigationDelegate = new WebViewDelegate();
            SetNativeControl(webView);
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(Element.Uri)));
        }
    }
}
public class WebViewDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate, INSUrlConnectionDataDelegate
{
    public override void DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(WKWebView webView, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge, Action<NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSUrlCredential> completionHandler)
    {
        //base.DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(webView, challenge, completionHandler);
        completionHandler(NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, new NSUrlCredential("username", "password", NSUrlCredentialPersistence.ForSession));
        Console.WriteLine("We are authenticated");
        return;
    }
}
```

At last you can use this webView in the XAML:

```
<local:CustomWebView Uri="https://www.microsoft.com" HeightRequest="300"/>
```

Comment: it does not show nothing, seems like ok but not, if i replace with regular webview setting source property instead of your custom uri property, it works, of course no authentication. anything? tks

Comment: Yes, you just need to set this uri to show your content. Does `DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge()` event call?

Comment: correcting the past coment, setting uri open the page in webview control(your code works), even in google.com the event DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge has been called, but in my own url the event is not called. My url is http, sholud be anything about this?

Comment: Please use https request to test this, this event called when the web view needs to respond to an authentication challenge. So the url you want to load needs to be a security request.

Comment: Actually my url point to a webcam (video stream) and does not support https, but in regular browser like Chrome the webcam´s url pops up the login form. I am stucked...

Comment: If only your particular web url doesn't call this event, it may be the problem of your url. Why not use the pop web page directly?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve using custom renderer in Xamarin.Forms

For iOS

```
    public class CustomWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomWebView,WKWebView>
{
    WKWebView webView;
    public CustomWebViewRenderer()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        webView = new WKWebView(Frame, new WKWebViewConfiguration());
        webView.NavigationDelegate = new MyWeakNavigationDelegate(this);
        SetNativeControl(webView);
    }

}

internal class MyWeakNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate, INSUrlConnectionDataDelegate
{
    private CustomWebViewRenderer customWebViewRenderer;

    public MyWeakNavigationDelegate(CustomWebViewRenderer customWebViewRenderer)
    {
        this.customWebViewRenderer = customWebViewRenderer;
    }

    public override void DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(WKWebView webView, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge, Action<NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSUrlCredential> completionHandler)
    {
        completionHandler(NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, new NSUrlCredential("username", "password", NSUrlCredentialPersistence.ForSession));
        Console.WriteLine("We are authenticated");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems you link the dots, but the customWebView does not show anything, not even a simple website url, with no autentication, anything else? tks