# Handle custom events in Webview Renderer

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, webview

i'm trying to handle a event from a custom webview but the event isn't fired at all, i'll put some code here

in my PCL project CustomWebview.cs

```
namespace TesteNovo
{
    public class CustomWebview : WebView
    {
        public EventHandler<int> Test;
    }
}
```

in my Android project CustomWebviewAndroid.cs

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Android.Webkit.WebView),typeof(CustomWebviewAndroid))]
namespace TesteNovo.Droid
{

    public class CustomWebviewAndroid : Android.Webkit.WebView
    {
        public CustomWebviewAndroid(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            var cl = new CustomWebViewClient();
            cl.ErroTeste += (a, b) => {
                var t = new CustomWebview();
                t.Test?.Invoke(this, b);

            };

            SetWebViewClient(cl);

        }

    }
}
```

in my Android project CustomWebviewClient

```
namespace TesteNovo.Droid
{
    public class CustomWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {


        public EventHandler<int> ErroTeste;

        public override void OnReceivedError(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error)
        {
            ErroTeste?.Invoke(this, 404);
            base.OnReceivedError(view, request, error);

        }

        public override void OnReceivedHttpError(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse)
        {
            base.OnReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
            ErroTeste?.Invoke(this, 404);
        }



    }
}
```

in my PCL Project Mainpage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TesteNovo;assembly=TesteNovo"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TesteNovo.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <local:CustomWebview   x:Name="teste1" Source="https://www.sincor.77seg.com.br/" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

        </local:CustomWebview>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

in my PCL MainPage.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        teste1.Test += async (a, b) => {
            await DisplayAlert(b.ToString(), "teste", "OK");

        };
    }
}
```

The first goal is to fire Test event when i receive any error from http request, the next goal is to choose what error will fire the Test event.

If you need more code or details just tell me in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Display the alert in `MainThread`:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    teste1.Test += async (a, b) => {

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
            await DisplayAlert(b.ToString(), "teste", "OK");
        });
    };
}
```

2.You should write the renderer of `CustomWebview` instead of `Android.Webkit.WebView`:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebview),typeof(CustomWebviewAndroid))]
namespace App81.Droid
{

    public class CustomWebviewAndroid : ViewRenderer<CustomWebview, Android.Webkit.WebView> {

        Context _context;

        public CustomWebviewAndroid(Context context) : base(context)
        {

            _context = context;

        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomWebview> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                if (Control == null)
                {
                    var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
                    webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

                    var cl = new CustomWebViewClient();
                    cl.ErroTeste += (a, b) => {
                        e.NewElement.Test?.Invoke(this, b);
                    };

                    webView.SetWebViewClient(cl);

                    SetNativeControl(webView);

                }

                Control.LoadUrl($"https://www.sincor.77seg.com.br/");
            }
        }
    }

    public class CustomWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {


        public EventHandler<int> ErroTeste;

        public override void OnReceivedError(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error)
        {
            ErroTeste?.Invoke(this, 404);
            base.OnReceivedError(view, request, error);

        }

        public override void OnReceivedHttpError(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse)
        {
            base.OnReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
            ErroTeste?.Invoke(this, 404);
        }
    }
}
```

3.Another way to achieve this is using [messaging-center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center), messaging-center can pass data between xxx.Android project and the shared project.

Comment: Ty bro, working just fine, btw, can you show me the iOS render aswell?

Comment: @GuilhermeNimer Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50694384/10539446);